# YYYYMMDD to YYYY/MM/DD in linux terminal

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I need a help with converting date in file from YYYYMMDD  to YYYY/MM/DD.

For example file.txt contains:

```
20200612 tuesday
20200315 monday
20200819 wednesday
```

should looks like:

```
2020/06/12 tuesday
2020/03/15 monday
2020/08/19 wednesday
```

I tried some codes with awk but no results at all :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: This should be simple using the substring operators in bash parameter expansion.

Comment: You could have also googled around stuff for this. That's where the actual learning is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with sed:

```sh
sed "s/\([[:digit:]]\{4\}\)\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)/\1\/\2\/\3/g"
```

Comment: It's a bit shorter and clearer with extended regex and a different delimiter: `sed -r "s,([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2}),\1/\2/\3,g"`. Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.